# SQL Server additional data from MAX value

Tags: sql-server, group-by, max, min

I have query which I rename as "Resultados", the output of this query is this:

[image: Resultados]

and then i have a query that returns the beggining and ending dates of consecutives dates in "Resultados" grouping by the fields GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal, GEN_idPaciente and GroupID

```
SELECT  GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal,
        GEN_idPaciente, 
        GroupID,
        Inicio = MIN(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones),
        Fin = MAX(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones),
        Dias= DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones), MAX(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones)) + 1
FROM Resultados
GROUP BY GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal, GEN_idPaciente, GroupID
```

the output of the query is this:

[image: Output]

this output is correct, but i need other fields that i cannot put in the group by clause, for example, i need the fields GEN_nombreCama, HOS_diagnostico_principalReceta_Indicaciones of the row of the MAX(date) which i rename as "Fin", with this conditions the expected output is this:

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
        ,GEN_idPaciente
        ,GroupID
        ,Inicio = MIN(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones) OVER (
            ORDER BY GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
                ,GEN_idPaciente
                ,GroupID
            )
        ,Fin = MAX(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones) OVER (
            ORDER BY GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
                ,GEN_idPaciente
                ,GroupID
            )
        ,Dias = DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones) OVER (
                ORDER BY GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
                    ,GEN_idPaciente
                    ,GroupID
                ), MAX(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones) OVER (
                ORDER BY GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
                    ,GEN_idPaciente
                    ,GroupID
                )) + 1
,,GEN_nombercama
        ,HOS_diagnostico_principalReceta_Indicaciones
    FROM Resultados
```

Comment: i was testing you answer but is not the output that i need, the extra fields that i need are missing and the values of "Inicio","Fin","Dias" are wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
    ,GEN_idPaciente
    ,GroupID
    ,Inicio
    ,Fin
    ,Dias = DATEDIFF(DAY, Inicio, Fin) + 1
    ,GEN_nombercama
    ,HOS_diagnostico_principalReceta_Indicaciones
FROM Resultados
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
        ,GEN_idPaciente
        ,GroupID
        ,Inicio = MIN(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones) OVER (
            ORDER BY GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
                ,GEN_idPaciente
                ,GroupID
            )
        ,Fin = MAX(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones) OVER (
            ORDER BY GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
                ,GEN_idPaciente
                ,GroupID
            )
        ,GEN_nombercama
        ,HOS_diagnostico_principalReceta_Indicaciones
    FROM Resultados
    ) a
```

Comment: now i have the extra fields but the values of "Inicio","Fin","Dias" are still wrong

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT 
    r1.GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal,
    r1.GEN_idPaciente,
    r1.GroupID,
    r1.GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal, 
    r1.GEN_idPaciente,
    r2.Inicio,
    r2.Fin,
    r2.Dias
FROM Resultados r1
INNER JOIN (SELECT  GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal,
                    GEN_idPaciente, 
                    GroupID,
                    Inicio = MIN(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones),
                    Fin = MAX(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones),
                    Dias= DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones), MAX(HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones)) + 1
            FROM Resultados
            GROUP BY GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal, GEN_idPaciente, GroupID
            ) AS r2 ON r1.GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal = r2.GEN_idMedicamento_Arsenal
                AND r1.GEN_idPaciente = r2.GEN_idPaciente
                AND r1.GroupID = r2.GroupID
                AND r1.HOS_fecha_recetaReceta_Indicaciones = r2.Fin
```

Comment: Hi, this works, but i am going to test this query with more data in the database to see how efficient is, thanks!!